# writing a column data of a groupby object to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df' which contains patient data. I want to create a network of patient movement from that data. The data looks like the following:

```
ID      start_date          stop_date           ward               bed
11111   15/12/2015 13:42    20/01/2016 12:55    Hematology         537-1
11111   30/10/2015 19:40    14/12/2015 16:44    ICU                184-2
11111   14/12/2015 16:44    15/12/2015 13:42    Internal Medicine  537-1
11127   05/11/2015 12:49    11/11/2015 14:42    Anestesiology      304
11127   11/11/2015 14:42    11/11/2015 16:12    Anestesiology      348-2
11127   04/11/2015 12:07    05/11/2015 12:49    General surgery    325-3
11127   11/11/2015 16:12    18/11/2015 21:24    General surgery    348-2
11127   18/11/2015 21:24    02/01/2016 06:45    ICU                183-5
11132   06/11/2015 17:24    30/11/2015 18:11    Internal Medicine  528-2
11132   30/11/2015 18:11    02/12/2015 17:04    Cardiology         539-1
11132   02/12/2015 17:04    03/12/2015 20:40    Internal Medicine  557-1
11132   03/12/2015 20:40    11/01/2016 18:00    Internal Medicine  536-1
```

It has separate columns for patient ID, start date, stop date, ward, bed. As you see in the data, a patient ID is appearing multiple times and I want to look at the entries related to every patient and also start dates are not properly sorted out. I used groupby in pandas to group entries related to patient ID and also sorted out based on start date:

```
grouped = df.sort_values(['ID','start_date'],ascending=True).groupby('ID')
```

This works fine but the next things is I wanted to create a directed edge list (or an adjacency matrix by wards) based on wards. For example, patient ID 11111 was first admitted to ICU, then moved to internal medicine and then to Hematology and to get an edge list like this.

```
Number     From                    To                            
1          ICU                     Internal Medicine             
2          Internal Medicine       Hematology                     
3          General surgery         Anestesiology                 
4          Anestesiology           Anestesiology                 
5          Anestesiology           General surgery               
6          General surgery         ICU                           
7          Internal Medicine       Cardiology                    
8          Cardiology              Internal Medicine             
9          Internal Medicine       Internal Medicine
```

After creating the full edge list, I wanted to see how many patients in total move from (let's say) ICU to Internal Medicine and count the entries from ICU to Internal Medicine and use that as a weight for network plot. Any suggestion, how could I do that in Pandas? I tried to loop over grouped data using "for name, group in grouped:" and `print(group['ward'])` shows the ward entries for every patient but I cannot write this information to another dataframe or list. Any help will be extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Dataset:

```
{'ID': {0: 11111,
  1: 11111,
  2: 11111,
  3: 11127,
  4: 11127,
  5: 11127,
  6: 11127,
  7: 11127,
  8: 11132,
  9: 11132,
  10: 11132,
  11: 11132},
 'bed': {0: '537-1',
  1: '184-2',
  2: '537-1',
  3: '304',
  4: '348-2',
  5: '325-3',
  6: '348-2',
  7: '183-5',
  8: '528-2',
  9: '539-1',
  10: '557-1',
  11: '536-1'},
 'start_date': {0: '15/12/2015 13:42',
  1: '30/10/2015 19:40',
  2: '14/12/2015 16:44',
  3: '05/11/2015 12:49',
  4: '11/11/2015 14:42',
  5: '04/11/2015 12:07',
  6: '11/11/2015 16:12',
  7: '18/11/2015 21:24',
  8: '06/11/2015 17:24',
  9: '30/11/2015 18:11',
  10: '02/12/2015 17:04',
  11: '03/12/2015 20:40'},
 'stop_date': {0: '20/01/2016 12:55',
  1: '14/12/2015 16:44',
  2: '15/12/2015 13:42',
  3: '11/11/2015 14:42',
  4: '11/11/2015 16:12',
  5: '05/11/2015 12:49',
  6: '18/11/2015 21:24',
  7: '02/01/2016 06:45',
  8: '30/11/2015 18:11',
  9: '02/12/2015 17:04',
  10: '03/12/2015 20:40',
  11: '11/01/2016 18:00'},
 'ward': {0: 'Hematology',
  1: 'ICU',
  2: 'Internal Medicine',
  3: 'Anestesiology',
  4: 'Anestesiology',
  5: 'General surgery',
  6: 'General surgery',
  7: 'ICU',
  8: 'Internal Medicine',
  9: 'Cardiology',
  10: 'Internal Medicine',
  11: 'Internal Medicine'}}
```

Comment: Interesting question. In my past experience, the edge weight is normally calculated within the network mapping library. Have you tried that, or do you explicitly want to get access to that data in Pandas first?

Comment: I haven't tried network mapping library. I will check that. But still, I would like to sort data first in Pandas because I have to do few other analytics on the sorted data.

Comment: Fair play. Will have a look to see if I can answer, but I have had good experience with these network libraries: NetworkX (easy to implement, pure python) or graph-tool (faster but more complex install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first group by "ID". Shift 1 cell back and add it back. Then drop the nan part. (Assuming data is sorted by ID and Dates.)

```
df_edges = df["ward"].to_frame()
df_edges["To"] = df.groupby("ID").shift(-1)["ward"]
df_edges.dropna()


    ward                 To
0   Hematology           ICU
1   ICU                  Internal Medicine
3   Anestesiology        Anestesiology
4   Anestesiology        General surgery
5   General surgery      General surgery
6   General surgery      ICU
8   Internal Medicine    Cardiology
9   Cardiology           Internal Medicine
10  Internal Medicine    Internal Medicine
```

We would want to shift it back because we assume the data is sorted and thus we can use next row's `ward` as current row's `To` part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the edge list:

```
# Assuming you already have the data in memory as `df`
df.sort_values(["ID", "start_date"], inplace=True)  # sort by patient ID and start_date

def get_target_ward(row, frame):
 row_index = row.name
 curr_ID = row["ID"]
 try:
     if df.loc[row_index + 1, "ID"] == curr_ID:
         return df.loc[row_index + 1, "ward"]
     else:
         return None
 except KeyError:
     return None

# Create a new column in the dataset that marks the next ward if they have one,
# otherwise populate with None
df["target_ward"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_target_ward(x, df), axis=1)
# Now you can group by the combination of current and next ward
df.groupby(["ward", "target_ward"]).count()
# Optional - drop any rows without a next steps, to only get the edge list
df.dropna(axis=0, how="any").groupby(["ward", "target_ward"]).count()
```

Note - this relies on an index of ascending numerical IDs. There are probably more elegant ways to get the next row but I'm not aware of any from my personal experience.

Comment: Thanks Phil for taking time to write the code. It works but at some places, I figured out that it mess up with the entries especially when the patient ID changes from one to next patient. But the code from Tai works perfect.

Comment: I just had a look at Tai's code and have one question. I assumed that the "ID" column was patient ID. In that case, the simple "shift" approach won't work because the next row could be for a different patient rather than ther termination if the journey. That was why I added the complexity of checking whether the ID was consistent. Let me know if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I see what's happening with the `.shift(-1)` operation. @tai has the most elegant answer. And I'll make use of that in future too! :)

Comment: I tried to plot the edgelist (the one created above with Tai code) using networkx and it does plot a network but does not take into account the weight. I understand that the weight column is not present in the dataframe. But now how could i combine directed entries (lets say from Hematology - ICU) and count the number of occurence in total for this pair. This counting should not include Hematology  - ICU because it is the opposite direction edge.

Comment: df_edges.groupby(['Ward', 'To']) does show the number of occurences for every pair but I am having difficulty in writing that grouped information to a kind of edge list. Any further suggestion?

Comment: df_edges.groupby(['Ward', 'To']).size().reset_index(name = "weight") seems to work to get an edge list with weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two columns strings, so you will create unique features like:

```
'UCU_to_Internal_Medicine'
```

Than you can group and count this features.